# REpeat and DEfense

Tags: pronunciation

The words "defense" and "repeat" are more and more frequently being pronounced DE-fense and RE-peat; i.e., with the accent on the first syllable rather than the second. They seem to have originated in sports broadcasting ("The 49er DE-fense has broken down; the Lakers are hoping for a RE-peat of their last road trip") and carried over to everyday usage. I am curious as to whether these mispronunciations are as common in the UK as they are in the U.S.

Comment: *Repeat* is only accented on the first syllable if it is a ***noun***. This is quite typical when a verb gets nouned. [See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun).

Comment: @Peter indirectly gives the answer: deriving a noun from a verb by moving the stress to the first syllable is quite a common process in English. In some cases, like _repeat_ or _defence_, there are nouns that happen to be stressed like their corresponding verbs—something that appears systematically irregular. What could be simpler than to move the stress to the first syllable in order to make them fit the system better? This is known as ***analogy*** and is one of the main driving forces of language change.

Comment: @Peter: Is it actually the *norm* for Americans to stress the first syllable in (noun) "repeat"? In BrE I'd only expect this to be done with "offence/defence" when the two words are being *contrasted with each other*, and it would be virtually unheard-of to do that with "repeat" because there's nothing like a "peat" against which to contrast.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, it's more common for Americans to stress the *re* when it's a noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think it's that common in musical contexts, For other meanings it's quite common, but I don't know whether it's the dominant pronunciation.

Comment: "RE-peat" as a noun is common in the US in a variety of contexts ("I wanted to watch some TV tonight, but everything's a RE-peat"), but I've never heard "DE-fense" outside the context of sports--or really, I'm not sure I've ever heard it outside the context of American football, specifically.

Comment: @Peter: Well, there are two complementary principles involved here - both perfectly logical, and tending towards "standardisation". Stressing the first syllable of a *noun* usage distinguishes it from a *verb* (I can't see that's necessary for the purposes of *disambiguation*, but it does reflect standardisation). And stressing the ***re-*** prefix emphasises that it's *not the first one* - but I might do that anyway if I REtype something a second time, regardless of whether I might also (admittedly, rarely) refer to the revised version as "a REtype".

Comment: There are some local lects in the US characterized by widespread shifting of noun stress to first syllable. Typical words are _POlice, UMbrella, INsurance, CIGarette_ etc. They're sometimes  called "P/U" dialects as a mnemonic for _POlice UMbrella_

Comment: I wonder if "RE-peat" could also be a reverse derivation from "three-peat".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Can you move your answer to an Answer so I can get this off of the Unanswered list? :)

Answer (score 2):

In his initial comment, Peter Shor indirectly gives the answer: deriving a noun from a verb by moving the stress to the first syllable is quite a common process in English.

In some cases, like repeat or defence, there are nouns that happen to be stressed like their corresponding verbs—something that does not fit the general, productive system and therefore appears to be irregular to some speakers. But what could be simpler than to move the stress to the first syllable, and thereby make them fit the productive system?

The process underlying this regularisation is known as *analogy* (subconsciously knowing and recognising a regular pattern, and then tweaking away at forms and paradigms that don’t fit this pattern until they do and become regular). It is one of the two main driving forces of how languages change, along with *sound change* (or *sound laws*). The latter is the more or less unconditioned development of one sound into another (or none at all) in a specific environment, which often makes what was before a regular form/paradigm look suddenly irregular. When this happens, the language becomes more irregular and harder to keep in your head—enter analogy, to make things nice and easy again.

Sadly, there is no way of predicting or structuring sound change and analogy—sometimes one takes over in a language for a while; sometimes the other; and sometimes both go hand in hand.

Comment: So the noun versus verb pronunciation rule also holds when both are different words? (In this case, defense versus defend)

Comment: @Bananach It’s not really a rule at all, but yes: as long as the verb and the noun are clearly related, as _defend_ and _defence_ obviously are, then the pattern of stressing the noun on the first syllable can be applied.